# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when sending to oracle aq

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I am getting the following exception in my Spring application:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/Transaction
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsSession.<init>(AQjmsSession.java:364)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsConnection.createSession(AQjmsConnection.java:1130)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createSession(JmsAccessor.java:192)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:475)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:570)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:658)
    at com.company.service.JmsMessageSender.sendMessage(JmsMessageSender.java:19)
    at com.company.service.TradeService.processTrade(TradeService.java:72)
    at com.company.task.TradeProcessingTask.run(TradeProcessingTask.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.Transaction
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 12 more
```

I have configured an `Oracle AQ` as follows where I want to push some trade messages to:

```
import static oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory.getQueueConnectionFactory;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("oracle")
public class OracleAQConfiguration {

    @NotNull
    private String url;

    @NotNull
    private String aqname;

    @NotNull
    private String aquser;

    @NotNull
    private String aqpassword;

    @NotNull
    private String driver;


    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws Exception {
        Properties info = new Properties();

        info.put("driver-name", driver);
        info.put("user", aquser);
        info.put("password", aqpassword);
        return getQueueConnectionFactory(url, info);
    }


        //setter and getters
}
```

A `JmsMessageSender` implementation as follows:

```
@Component
@EnableJms
public class JmsMessageSender implements MessageSender {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(String queueName, String message) {
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, message);
        log.info("Message sent: {}", message);
    }

}
```

The service which receives trade object and uses an executor service to submit tasks:

```
@Service
public class TradeService {

    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    @Autowired
    private TradeRequestBuffer buffer;

    @Autowired
    private JmsMessageSender jmsMessageSender;


    @Value("${oracle.aqname}")
    private String aqname;


    public void submitTradeForProcessing(Trade trade) {

        final TradeProcessingTask tradeProcessingTask = new TradeProcessingTask(this, trade);
        executorService.execute(() -> buffer.executeTask(tradeProcessingTask));

    }

    public void processTrade(Trade trade) {

        Optional<String> xmlTradeMessage = XmlParserUtil.marshall(trade);
        if (xmlTradeMessage.isPresent()) {
            jmsMessageSender.sendMessage(aqname, xmlTradeMessage.get());
            updateTradeStatus(tradeProcessingContext);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like `javax.transaction.Transaction` is specific to Enterprise Edition (EE), is that what you're running?

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b I am not using this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like one of your libraries is missing a required dependency `transaction-api`

If you're using Maven try

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.transaction/javax.transaction-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2

Comment: Why is this required please in my context?

Comment: Because your `JmsTemplate` is using `AQjmsSession` which in turn is using a method out of the `transaction-api` but it can't find it because that api is not present in your enviornment thus it is throwing the error